# Gather items maximazing similarity

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

Say there's a group of 50 students in a class, and we have determined the similarity between all of them, in pairs (e.i. student 1 and student 2 have a similarity of 10, student 1 and student 3 a similarity of 8, and so on).

Now I want to find, between all of those 50 students, the group of 8 students which have the greatest similarity between all of them (it may be more than one group with the biggest score).

Are there any methods so solve this without brute force?

Comment: It depends on how you define "similarity" for more than one student. The mean of the pairwise similarities, perhaps?

Comment: @Nilknarf the way this 'similarity' is measured is trivial (it could be the number of hours working together, number of tasks developed together...)